# Microsoft Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a use case in which:

1. I want to store images in Microsoft Blob storage,
2. Search images by giving text input like '**water**' then all images which contain water in any way should appear in the search result.

I followed below link:
https://github.com/Azure/LearnAI-Cognitive-Search/blob/master/05-Lab-2-Image-Skills.md

But here I get to know that there are only 2 predefined skills which are `ImageAnalysisSkill` and `OcrSkill` which do not give full images as the search result.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Programatically, you can use the Image Analysis Cognitive Skill to automatically extract tags from the images.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-image-analysis for more information on this skill.

Your skill would look something like this:

```
{  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.ImageAnalysisSkill",
    "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
    "visualFeatures": [
        "Tags",
        "Description"
    ],
    "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "image",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "tags",
            "targetName": "myTags"
        },
        {
            "name": "description",
            "targetName": "myDescription"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in the index, make sure to create a field of type Collection(Edm.String) to contain the list of tags. Let's call that the *imageTags* field. Make sure that field is searchable.

In the output field mappings (a property of the indexer) you will need to map the list of tags to the newly created imageTags field as follows:

```
   "outputFieldMappings": [
       {
           "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/myDescription/tags/*",
           "targetFieldName": "imageTags"
       }
```

This will ensure that each of the tags found on the images are insterted in the imageTags array.

Please also read this document that explains how to extract normalized_imagesif you are not familiar with that already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios